# How to prevent trail of shapes when repainting canvas - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jsfiddle

I have the start of a project here and ran into a little issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/kylebrown219/gn10Lh8g/

In the jsFiddle you can click and create as many circles as you wish. When you press 'Spawn' you will see a Rectangle move across the screen. How do I get rid of the trail, without erasing the circles behind it?
I think this is where the issue is:

```
context.clearRect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs; if you just are after animation you can use this little trick:

Set the current content of canvas as background to the element *before* drawing the rectangle:

```
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ")";
```

Then, when animating, clear the whole canvas, then redraw rectangle at current position:

```
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);
```

**[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn10Lh8g/48/)**

To clear everything just reset the background style ("none") and clear.

You will of course have to limit the spawn button, or store the circles (as objects) for redraw (which in that case you could have used to redraw the background).